# Variable in HTTPGET

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Can anyone please help me understand what is the error in code below; and please correct it...

```
%%httpget "http://mediaalpha.com/html.html?{"ua":"_","ip":"_","version":17,"data":{"zip":"**%%=v(@zipCodeShort)=%%**"},"api_token":"xxxxx","placement_id":"xxxxx"}"%%
```

If I run this with hard-coded zip codes then it works fine...

```
%%httpget "http://mediaalpha.com/html.html?{"ua":"_","ip":"_","version":17,"data":{"zip":**"08854**"},"api_token":"xxxxx","placement_id":"xxxxx"}"%%
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest something like this using the [concat()](https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/string/Concat.html) function.

```
%%[

var @url, @zipCodeShort
set @zipCodeShort = AttributeValue("zipCodeShort")

set @url = concat('http://mediaalpha.com/html.html?{"ua":"","ip":"","version":17,"data":{"zip":"', @zipCodeShort, '"},"api_token":"xxxxx","placement_id":"xxxxx"}')

]%%
%%=httpget(@url)=%%
```

You have to be careful how you reference AMPScript variables inside and outside AMPScript blocks.  Inside AMPScript (`%%[` `]%%`) blocks or in functions (like [httpget](https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/http/HTTPGet.html)), use `@varName`.  Outside AMPScript blocks, you need to use `%%=v(@varName)=%%`.